# How to create an indexed set of vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

So, I wish that, for a given integer n, I could create a sequence of vectors named O1, O2,..., On, all defined to be columns of the identity matrix.
My first thought was to run

```
for (i in 1:n){
  Oi <- diag(,n)[,i]
}
```

But all this does is create one vector called Oi equal to diag(,n)[,n] while none of the other vectors are stored.
Does anyone have an idea as to how to solve this?

Comment: Can you please show the expected result?

Comment: Creating a bunch of variables with different names in the global namespace can be very messy. It's better to create related objects in lists (which is easily done with `lappply`). Then you get things out with `O[[1]]` rather than `O1`. `O<-lapply(1:n, function(i) diag(,n)[,i])`.

Comment: Is that the same as `x <- diag(4); split(x, col(x))`?

Comment: When R comes across the name `Oi`, it doesn't see it as being related to the existing name `i`.

Comment: @MrFlick I just tried creating a list and it appears to have worked. Thanks! But is there a way to give it a specific generic name? I mean, is there a way for R still to call it Oi instead of O[i]? (Just for convinience)

Comment: @MrFlick's suggestion is actually better in terms of variable management. If you really want separated objects Oi however, try `for (i in 1:n) {assign(paste0("O", i), diag(,n)[,i])}`.

Comment: @ytu That's precisely what I needed. I understamd that creating a list might be better, but I needed the notation to make input easier, because it'll be written in terms of O1, O2, etc. ç, besides, my script is simple enough that I don't think there'll be many complications as to variable management